# Get rows between two values of a column using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose there is a data frame as follows:

```
df = {
'Period': [1996,'Jan','Feb','March',1997,'Jan','Feb','March',1998,'Jan','Feb','March']
'Some-Values': [,'a','b','c',,'d','e','f',,'g',h','i']
}
```

and the rows between the values `1996` and `1997` needs to be extracted such that the resulting data frame is as follows:

```
df_res = {
    'Period': ['Jan','Feb','March']
    'Some-Values': ['a','b','c']
}
```

I am currently trying Pandas for this but am unable to find a solution.

Comment: Can anyone please do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your dataframe into "correct" way , then we can getting the information by using year information

```
df['Year']=df.loc[df['Some-Values']=='','Period']
df.Year=df.Year.ffill()
df=df.loc[df.Period!=df.Year,:]
df.loc[df.Year==1996,:]
Out[651]: 
  Period Some-Values  Year
1    Jan           a  1996
2    Feb           b  1996
3  March           c  1996
```

Answer (score 1):

One way via [`pd.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': [1996,'Jan','Feb','March',1997,'Jan','Feb',
                              'March',1998,'Jan','Feb','March'],
                   'Some-Values': ['','a','b','c','','d','e','f','','g','h','i']})

res = df.iloc[(df['Period'] == 1996).idxmax()+1:(df['Period'] == 1997).idxmax()]

print(res)

  Period Some-Values
1    Jan           a
2    Feb           b
3  March           c
```

For readability, you can use a `slice` object:

```
slicer = slice((df['Period'] == 1996).idxmax()+1,
               (df['Period'] == 1997).idxmax())

res = df.iloc[slicer]
```