# Flag rows between two values of a column in a group using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have my dummy data like below

```
df = data.frame(name = c(rep("Anna",8),rep("Jenny",7)),
                id = c(100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,250,250,250,250,250,250,250),
                time = c("t2","t3","t5","t1","t7","t2","t1","t5","t1","t2","t6","t2","t8","t6","t5"),                stringsAsFactors = F)

> df
    name  id time
1   Anna 100   t2
2   Anna 100   t3
3   Anna 100   t5
4   Anna 100   t1
5   Anna 100   t7
6   Anna 100   t2
7   Anna 100   t1
8   Anna 100   t5
9  Jenny 250   t1
10 Jenny 250   t2
11 Jenny 250   t6
12 Jenny 250   t2
13 Jenny 250   t8
14 Jenny 250   t6
15 Jenny 250   t5
```

My expected output is, for every `id` group, i want to `flag` values between and including **t2** and **t5** using`time` variable - There will be multiple cases of this in each group and the code should be able to exclude some broken cases as like in the example below

```
 > df
    name  id time Flag
1   Anna 100   t2    1
2   Anna 100   t3    1
3   Anna 100   t5    1
4   Anna 100   t1    0
5   Anna 100   t7    0
6   Anna 100   t2    1
7   Anna 100   t1    1
8   Anna 100   t5    1
9  Jenny 250   t1    0
10 Jenny 250   t2    0
11 Jenny 250   t6    0
12 Jenny 250   t2    1
13 Jenny 250   t8    1
14 Jenny 250   t6    1
15 Jenny 250   t5    1
```

Am asking this using `dplyr()`mode as i can add more grouping variables in future for scalability. I searched on how to use `which()` inside dplyr functions, not resulted in much, i found one python equivalent here [Get rows between two values of a column using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740250/get-rows-between-two-values-of-a-column-using-python)

Edit1: I have multiple t2-t5 sections in each group that needs to be flagged. Thanks @ronak for bringing it up

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a better option to this but this works

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(flag  = +(row_number() %in% which(time == "t2"):which(time == "t5")))


#  name     id time   flag
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1 Anna    100 t2        1
#2 Anna    100 t3        1
#3 Anna    100 t5        1
#4 Jenny   250 t1        0
#5 Jenny   250 t2        1
#6 Jenny   250 t3        1
#7 Jenny   250 t4        1
#8 Jenny   250 t5        1
```

This is assuming you have only one "t2" and "t5" in every group.

Same logic using base R `ave`

```
as.numeric(with(df, ave(time, name, FUN = function(x) 
      +(1:length(x) %in% which(x == "t2"):which(x == "t5")))))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple "t2" and "t5" no need to take group into consideration since you want to flag them anyway. We can use `mapply` and create a sequence of index to mark flag as 1.

```
df$flag <- 0
df$flag[unlist(mapply(":", which(df$time == "t2"), which(df$time == "t5")))] <- 1
```

and the `dplyr` version for the same is

```
df %>%
  mutate(flag = +(row_number() %in% 
          unlist(map2(which(time == "t2"), which(time == "t5"), seq))))
```

Comment: yes i have multiple sections of t2-t5 to flag in each group, the above code has limitation foe only one appearance

Comment: so in case of multiple t2-t5 in each group what would be the output? Can you update your example with that?

Comment: the code should be able to flag all that sections between t2-t5 as 1 in each group

Comment: Ya, the code works in base R mode, I am trying to achieve this within dplyr. Thanks for this

Comment: @SaiPrabhanjanReddy updated with `tidyverse` version .

Comment: I have edited the example with perfect cases to be flagged. Thanks for the input

Answer (score -1):

The following is a simple approach that you might consider:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(flag = ifelse(time %in% c("t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"), 1, 0))
```

This will flag the data like you described and is readable.

```
   name  id time flag
1  Anna 100   t2    1
2  Anna 100   t3    1
3  Anna 100   t5    1
4 Jenny 250   t1    0
5 Jenny 250   t2    1
6 Jenny 250   t3    1
7 Jenny 250   t4    1
8 Jenny 250   t5    1
```